# Is there a built in URL class in .Net?

Tags: asp.net

I'm spending time breaking up URLs into `protocol://domain:port/path/filename` but there must be a built in class, all I can find is `System.Security.Policy.Url`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) is what you're looking for